# rails: create Parent, if doesn't exist, whilte creating child record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes

Any best practices for the following?:

I have Manufacturer model that has_many Inventory

In my new Inventory form I want a field that maps to Manufacturer.name so that when one 
submits the new Inventory form the app:

- searches for a manufacturer with the 'name' from the form

  - if it exists then assign the id to @inventory.manufacturer_id and save @inventory
  - if it doesn't exist then create the manufacturer with the 'name' from the form, assign the id to @inventory.manufacturer_id and save
  - have validations work on the new Inventory form

    - such that, if the the Inventory form fails validation on a field other than 'name'

      - the 'name' field will be repopulated with whatever the user entered (but a new manufacturer is not created unless the form passes validation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try like this:

```
class Inventory < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...

  belongs_to :manufacturer

  ...

  def manufacturer_name
    manufacturer && manufacturer.name
  end

  def manufacturer_name=(value)
    self.manufacturer = Manufacturer.find_by_name(value)
    self.manufacturer ||= Manufacturer.new(:name => value)
  end

  ...

end
```

In this case you should output manufacturer_name text field on Inventory form.

Comment: lest - this is lookin good!! I will implement tomorrow and get back.  thanks!