# Rails Puzzle: Check if a nested value exists, if it does don't save it but save the child values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have a challenge that I have been struggling to tackle for the last few hours.

I have a form with nested attributes. Each Post has and belongs to many Locations. I need each Location to be unique but I also need to be able to add the same location to many posts. Ideally this validation would be done within the model.

- So, in my posts form what currently happens is a user 'adds a
  location', they then search the foursquare API for a location.
- Upon submit this is saved into the Locations table with the location name and the
  longitude and latitude, there is a Locations_Posts table which ties
  these together.
- What needs to happen is the posts model should check
  if a location exists, if it does, don't add anything to Locations,
  just add the relevant data to the Locations_Posts table.

After some research I have worked out that I need something like this:

```
*Posts.rb*

# =================
# = Location validations = 
# = If location exists then just add to locations_posts, else create new location =

def locations_attributes
location && location.name
end

def locations_attributes=(value)
self.location = Location.find_by_name(value)
self.location ||= Location.new(:name => value)
end
```

(Stolen from [rails: create Parent, if doesn't exist, whilte creating child record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588811/rails-create-parent-if-doesnt-exist-whilte-creating-child-record))

However, I'm getting errors such as:

```
Unknown key: 0
```

I think I must be close with this snippet but need some help to get over the last hurdle!

Thanks in advance,

James

Answer (score 1):

try using:

```
def locations_attributes=(value)
  self.location = Location.find_or_create_by_name(value)
end
```

Comment: Hi! This seems to be going through ok and elements are created, however it does not appear to be finding the name values when they pre exist. It is simply saving the value. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

in rails 4 this worked perfectly. Thanks to all.

```
def locations_attributes=(value)
  self.location = Location.find_or_create_by(value)
end
```

This checks uniqueness across all attributes passed in for location.