# Check if record exist, if yes update else create new - nested forms - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I'm using rails 3.2. I have a nested form for "Samples". A "Patient" can have several "Samples" but a "Sample" can only have one "Patient".

Patient primary key is "id" but is has also 4 foreign keys: nid, province_id, district_id and facility_id.

Here's the models (i'm trying to show only the relevant code):

Patient.rb

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :date_of_birth, :infant_name, :nid, :province_id, :district_id, :facility_id, :gender_id, :gender_atributes

  belongs_to :gender
  belongs_to :province
  belongs_to :district
  belongs_to :facility
  has_many :samples

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :gender

  validates :province_id, presence: true
  validates :district_id, presence: true
  validates :facility_id, presence: true
  validates :nid, presence: true
  #To validate uniqueness of patient, that is, one with unique nid, province, district and facility
  validates_uniqueness_of :nid, :scope => [:province_id, :district_id, :facility_id]

end
```

Sample.rb

```
class Sample < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :dateOfSample, :nrOrdem, :patient_id,:facility_id, :province_id, :district_id

  belongs_to :facility
  belongs_to :patient
  belongs_to :province
  belongs_to :district

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :patient

end
```

What I want is to avoid corrupted data on pacient, that is, to have different patients with the same (nid, province_id, district_id and facility_id).

Right now the nested form for sample lets me create a new patient and if I try to create a new one with the same (nid, province_id, district_id and facility_id) I get an error saying that the "nid is already taken".

But, as a Patient can have different samples, I want to (while trying to create the record) check if the patient already exists, if it does than adds "patient_id" to the "sample" record, otherwise creates a new one.

It would be great to also show a message saying that the patient already exists and fill the corresponding data on the form, but for now I'll be glad if it adds the patient_id to the sample record, ignoring the rest of the patient fields in the nested form.

I tried to implement something like this
[rails: create Parent, if doesn't exist, whilte creating child record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588811/rails-create-parent-if-doesnt-exist-whilte-creating-child-record) but it didn't work.

How can I solve this?

**EDIT**

Here's how the code ended up after @James Mason  help.
On Sample.rb

```
def patient_attributes=(attrs)
  self.patient = Patient.where({:nid => attrs[:nid], province_id: province_id, district_id: district_id, facility_id: facility_id}).first_or_initialize(attrs)
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`first_or_create` and/or `first_or_initialize`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_querying.html#find-or-build-a-new-object). In this case, since you care whether the record already existed, you probably want the initialize version.

```
@patient = Patient.where({nid: nid, province_id: province_id, district_id: district_id, facility_id: facility_id}).first_or_initialize
@show_exists_message = !@patient.new_record?
@patient.save
```

You can either put this code in your controller's `create` action, or, since you're using nested attributes, define a custom `Sample#patient_attributes=` method:

```
class Sample < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patient
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :patient

  def patient_attributes=(attrs)
    self.patient = Patient.where(attrs).first_or_initialize(attrs) 
    @show_exists_message = !@patient.new_record?
  end
end
```

Comment: I'll put that on the "create" action of the "sample" controller?

Comment: I think we're almost there. I put the code in the sample model, but I had to do this: `self.patient = Patient.where({:nid => attrs[:nid], province_id: province_id, district_id: district_id, facility_id: facility_id}).first_or_initialize`for it to search only for these fields. It lets me add "patient_id" to sample record if patient already exists, but it doesn't pass the rest of the patient attrs if the patient doesn't exist... If it doesn't exist, how can I pass the rest of the params in attrs? thanks

Comment: Pass the attrs to first_or_initialize, I think. See updated answer.

Comment: It seems to be working :) I wasn't able to put the part of the message working, but the rest is working fine. I'll update my question with the final result of the code!Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JamesMason thank you this was most helpful. I'm assuming that because we are using first_or_create then we should not have validations for uniqueness? any advice much appreciated

Comment: @BKSpugeon you should probably ask a new question with full details on what you're trying to do. If you only use `first_or_create` to make your records, the validations would just add extra insurance.